# If a public key is rotated out for session that used the key to authenticate, do running queries fail?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, key-pair

If my session is authenticated with a keypair, and I start a query that runs so long that my key gets rotated out, does my query fail?

I couldn't find documentation, and I haven't experimented myself. I'd prefer the official answer to empirical evidence.

Comment: It should not fail, but for better understanding - Say you change your key every X, do you want to know what happen to the query that runs longer than 2X?

Comment: Actually I think longer than X, since a key might expire the moment after my process starts.  I want to know if it is documented.

Comment: In Snowflake, key-pairs don’t expire. I suppose you/someone could have written a custom process to automatically rotate keys? Given that keys don’t expire, and will only be used when initiating a session, rotating a key won’t affect running sessions. Though Snowflake supports 2 keys to ensure that if you are rotating one there is always another available

Comment: Thanks NickW, you are right, instead of expire I should have said "gets replaced by a new key"